# RuntimeError: A column was specified that does not exist

Tags: arcpy, cursor, runtimeerror

I have a script which reads a geodatabase table and calculate two fields based on existing fields.
This is my code:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

#overwrite output
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#Linear reference
def locateFeatures(fc,rts,tbl):
    arcpy.LocateFeaturesAlongRoutes_lr(fc, rts, 'RID', '0.1 Meters', tbl, 
    'RID LINE FMEASN TMEASN')

#add field Diff MEAS
def addFieldDif(tbl):
    arcpy.AddField_management(tbl,'DifFMEAS', 'DOUBLE')
    arcpy.AddField_management(tbl,'DifTMEAS', 'DOUBLE')

#calculate Diff MEAS
def calFieldDifMeas(fc):
    fdList = ['FMEASN','TMEASN','FMEAS','TMEAS','DifFMEAS','DifTMEAS']
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,fdList) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            row[4] = abs(row[0] - row[2])
            row[5] = abs(row[1] - row[3])
            cursor.UpdateRow(row)

fc = r'C:\Users\Gary\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\PplProt'
rts = r'C:\Users\Gary\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\PplRoute'
tbl = r'C:\Users\Gary\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\Locate_MEAS'
locateFeatures(fc,rts,tbl)
addFieldDif(tbl)
calFieldDifMeas(fc)
print'done!!'
```

When I run the script I get the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File ", line 31, in 
>       File "", line 21, in calFieldDifMeas
>    RuntimeError: A column was specified that does not exist.

Maybe this is a very silly error but I've started learning Python recently and I cannot find a fix anywhere. Can anybody give me a hint of what might be causing the error?

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov I have printed all fields and they all seem to be there. This is the error message:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<module1>", line 31, in <module>
  File "<module1>", line 21, in calFieldDifMeas
RuntimeError: A column was specified that does not exist.

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov thanks, this helped me to identify what I was doing wrong. I was actually selecting wrong fc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error `RuntimeError: A column was specified that does not exist.` usually comes from the cursor when you supply in the list of input fields a field that does not exist.

There are some things you can do for troubleshooting:

- Try printing all the fields in the feature class before using `da.UpdateCursor` using `arcpy.ListFields()`:

Code:

```
for f in fdList: 
  print f, f in [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields(fc)]
```

This should be done before creating a cursor. You should get `True` for all fields.

- Make sure you are using the correct feature class - check what feature class the variable `fc` refers to.

Answer (score 0):

More documentation on this process is here on the ArcGIS help site https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/arcpy/functions/listfields.htm